# Delphi - TStoredProc.Close (does it empty the set?)

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, bde

LEGACY ALERT - This is for Delphi 5 code.  (I know it is super old.  It is scheduled to be rewritten.... Some day.)

I am using the BDE and the TStoredProc object.  When I call Close, this normally clears my dataset.  However, I am seeing weird things happen so I thought I would ask this question.

If I have manually added rows to the dataset (i.e. via the Append method) then when I call close are they going to be deleted as well?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "weird things"?

Comment: Values are being posted to the database that have no relation to the current set.  (I am wondering if I have old data hanging round.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure with D5 and BDE, but I would say that you have to do an explicit **Post** to ensure the added record is actually stored.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont post they should be getting deleted